# Symfony2 delayed flashbag message when sending mail

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I've got an odd problem that I can't put my finger on.

In my controller, I'm sending an email using swiftmailer, setting a flash message using the session flashbag, and redirecting to another page.

```
public function testAction() {
    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('info', 'test flash message');

    $message = new \Swift_Message('test', 'test');
    $message->setTo('email@example.com');
    $message->setFrom('email@example.com');

    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home_page'));
}
```

After the redirect, I expect to see the flash message, but it seems that something happens when the mail is sent that makes the flash message delayed by one request.  That is, I don't see the flash message when I get to 'home_page', but I do if I reload the page after the redirect.

If I comment out the send() call or even set disable_delivery: true in the swiftmail configuration, the flash message works as expected.

I thought I might have found a bug, but when I created a new project (symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.4.1) and tried this, it works even when I send mail.  I've checked to make sure I'm using the same releases for swiftmailer, symfony, etc.  So, I'm sure it's something with my project, but I am out of ideas of where to go from here.

I'm using PHP 5.5.7, Symfony 2.4.1.

Thanks for your time

Comment: You say you rewrote this code from scratch but couldn't recreate the behaviour? Was the new testAction *completely* identical to the one above?

Comment: The only difference was the email message subject and body, negligible differences.  Of course there is a lot more going on than just what's in the action, so I'm starting by disabling some bundles.

Comment: @Jody I am getting the same error, have you found the solution ?

Comment: @SergioCosta I ended up not using the flashbag in controllers where emails are sent, and later stopped using them all-together because I had issues with the reverse-proxy.  I am certain the proxy was me doing something wrong, but I ran out of time for this project!  scp's answer below may be relevant as I was using the PdoSessionHandler.  I'll try to find some time to re-create this using two standard setups with the session handler being the only difference and see if that's the cause.

Comment: @Jody this is a known issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6417 and I've found a workaround for this. I posted my answer below.. regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's a bug when using PdoSessionHandler for storing sessions - if you use native session storage the problem goes away and the flash message works as expected with SwiftMailer.

The flash messages (app.session.flashbag) rely on sessions to store the data between page loads.

Comment: Thank you, I will read into this some more.  I did find this relevant thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222724/symfony2-pdo-session-with-flashbag which seems to confirm your suspicion, so I'll mark the question as accepted until I observe otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix is to disable spooling for SwiftMailer. I am still uncertain whether this is the actual solution, but it seems to work.
By disabling spooling, the mailer will block execution while sending the mail.

I commented out the line that enables spooling:

```
#spool:     { type: memory }
```

By default, the mailer will not use spooling but send the mail right away: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/email/spool.html

Comment: YOU SAVED MY LIFE !!!!!!!!!!  I was pulling my hair knowing it was something small. And BOOM !